# Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(name) returns null all the time

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

We used to use a variation of the groovy-script DSL cleanup methods to cleanup any Jenkins workspaces where the job had been deleted. The job is deleted when the respective GitHub branch no longer exists. We use the GitHub plugin and have MultiBranch jobs/workspaces.

Below is the code we used to use:

```
/*
  Delete workspaces with no jobs (for GitHubMultiBranch)
  Forked from https://gist.github.com/ceilfors/1400fd590632db1f51ca
*/

import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import jenkins.branch.*


/***************
 Main Functions
****************/

def out = new StringBuffer()
def workspaceRoot = Jenkins.instance.rootPath.child("workspace")  

def boolean isMultiBranch(String name) {
    def item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(name)
    return item in MultiBranchProject
}


/* Deletes any workspace tree that doesn't have a task.
*/
def deleteUnusedWorkspace(FilePath root, String path, Boolean dryRun) {
    root.list().each { child ->
        println "Examining " + child.name
        String fullName = path + child.name
        if (!child.name.endsWith("@tmp")) {
            // If it's a MultiBranch then recurse.
            if (isMultiBranch(fullName)) {
                deleteUnusedWorkspace(root.child(child.name), "$fullName/", dryRun)
            } else {
                // Checks if an item (job) exists.
                if (Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(fullName) == null) {
                    if (dryRun) {
                        println "Would Delete: $fullName "
                    } else {
                        println "Deleting: $fullName "
                        child.deleteRecursive()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


/***************
 Debuggery
***************/

/* Outputs class names of the root items and
   whether they happen to be MultiBranch.
*/
def printClasses(FilePath root, String path) {
    out << ' Debuggery '.center(15, "*") + '\n\n'
    out << "Item Name".padRight(40)
    out << "MultiBranch?".padRight(15)
    out << "Class Name\n\n"
    root.list().each { child ->
        String fullName = path + child.name
        className = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(fullName).getClass()
        multiBranch = isMultiBranch(fullName)
        out << "$child.name".padRight(40)
        out << "$multiBranch".padRight(15)
        out << "$className\n"
    }
    out << "\n\n"
}

//printClasses(workspaceRoot, "")

/***************
 Execution
***************/
println("Begin Task")
deleteUnusedWorkspace(workspaceRoot, "", false) // true = Dry-Run // false = Real
println("Task Complete\n")
```

Since the workspace directories are not nested now (new Jenkins deployment), we don't need to recurse. The problem is that the **Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName()** method just returns null. Any ideas?

Comment: do you use a standard or custom jenkins filesystem layout?

Comment: We use a standard layout I believe. That is, it hasn't been modified since we deployed Jenkins. The workspace layout looks like the following:

`./jenkinsroot/workspace/<repo-name>_<branch-name>_<hash>[@tmp]`

Comment: `Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName()` gets the job path and not a workspace path

Comment: Okay, yes - that is true. It still doesn't solve the issue of it always returning Null though? This is despite feeding getItemByFullName() the full path of the workspace. The idea is that if it returns Null for a given workspace path, the job doesn't exist and we can delete the workspace. Since it returns Null 100% of the time with correct workspace paths, something has changed since using the newer Jenkins version =)